# Joining a calculated field to a table within 1 query

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007

I have a field that when shortened to its 2 leftmost characters can be joined as a key field to another table.

When I do this I always have to do the LEFT([FieldName],2) bit in a query of its own, and then do the actual join in a second query.

Is there a way of accomplishing this within a single query?

Here's the syntax of the query that shaves off the 2 leftmost characters; let's call it `QueryA`:

```SQL
SELECT Left([TableA].[Field1],2) AS AbbrField1
FROM [TableA];
```

Here's the query that joins `QueryA` to another table based on that field "AbbrField1" I've had to create first; let's call it `QueryB`:

```SQL
SELECT [TableB].[Field2]
FROM [QueryA] 
LEFT JOIN [TableB] ON [QueryA].[AbbrField1] = [TableB].[Field1];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `JOIN` the tables using the `LEFT` function on the JOIN:

```
SELECT B.[Field2]
FROM [TableA] as A
LEFT JOIN [TableB] as B 
    ON Left(A.[Field1], 2) = B.[Field1];
```

This will remove the need for the second query.

*Note: this was tested in MS Access 2003.*

Comment: I had to use the `B` alias you created for `[TableB]` in the `SELECT` part before it would work, but works nicely after that. Thank you very much.

Comment: @MattHall sorry about that, I fat fingered it. Glad it is working now.